# Looking for a utility to remove MAC inutils files/folders

Tags: windows, macos, external-hard-drive

In fact, the problem is that i have those files on an External USB Hard Disk. If i connect it to the pc (on windows) and i remove the files on Recycle Bin, it doesnt remove the files forver. So, If I remove the hd and i reconnect, they will stay on the HD. In fact i can't remove them.

So that's happen on External HD!

Anyone know some utility that do this work?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any such utility in Windows, other than your <kbd>Delete</kbd> key. It doesn't make any sense that you can't delete them; the Mac is probably regenerating them each time you mount the drive there.

However, on the Mac side, you can use [BlueHarvest](http://www.zeroonetwenty.com/blueharvest4/). It's a simple utility that prevents the creation of .Trashes, .DS_Store files, and resource forks on removable drives. It can also remove the files from an existing drive: Simply drag the device you want to clean to the BlueHarvest icon.

[image: BlueHarvest]

If you do a particularly sizable amount of data shuffling between computers, trying to get rid of these files (and Windows generates its own, too) is a lot like chasing your tail. It's probably not worth the trouble.

Comment: Yeah, in fact i can't bind my friends to do this on their own computer :) So i'd like to remove them on mine :) Recently i've got DS_Store_Cleaner_1.5.0 on windows, but it only remove DS_Store files. I need somethings to remove any inutils files :)